# VBA PasteSpecial operation fails?

Tags: vba, excel

I try to cut a row from one listobject into another listobject:

```
'Create new row
Dim lNewRowNumber As Long
lNewRowNumber = loTrgt.DataBodyRange.Row + loTrgt.ListRows.Count
trgtWorkSheet.Rows(lNewRowNumber).EntireRow.Insert

'Cut old row
Dim lCutRow As Long
Dim lCutStartColumn As Long
Dim lCutEndColumn As Long
lCutRow = t.Row
lCutStartColumn = loSrc.Range.Column
lCutEndColumn = loSrc.Range.Column + loSrc.ListColumns.Count - 1

'Paste row
Dim lPasteRow As Long
Dim lPasteColumn As Long
lPasteRow = lNewRowNumber
lPasteColumn = loTrgt.Range.Column

t.Worksheet.Range(t.Worksheet.Cells(lCutRow, lCutStartColumn), t.Worksheet.Cells(lCutRow, lCutEndColumn)).Cut
trgtWorkSheet.Cells(lPasteRow, lPasteColumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

The makro stops on the last row of the code pasted above. It tells me that the paste operation of the range object failed. Any idea why this might be? I don't think it has to do with the listobjects, because I seem to get the problem when trying to cut and paste other rows as well using the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Cut`, try `Insert` instead of `PasteSpecial`. This is synonymous with "Insert Cut Cells" which you see when you are using the Excel interface:

```
trgtWorkSheet.Cells(lPasteRow, lPasteColumn).Insert
```

Also - make sure the cell you are pasting/inserting to is not in the range which is being cut.